# Add additional data to a task

Tags: node.js, bull.js

Newbee on bull.js, I'd like to know if it's possible to add additional parameters to a job.
I'd like add a companyId field to be able to request all jobs for a company for monitoring tasks by company.

Is there a way to make a things like :

`myQueue.add(jobData, companyId);`

Answer (score 0):

I will change my design, each jobs will add a log on success or fail with data provided in the task.

It's better, perhaps tired yesterday :-)